# I wish to know meaning of phrase / expression wacky duck

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrases, expressions, dictionaries

I am writing a story at the moment about one villain from a horror movie and I often need rhymes. English is not my mother tongue. I read on Urban Dictionary that "wacky duck" means a hit to a man's genitals. There is one example. I gave him a wacky duck after he stepped on my foot.

Here is a source

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wacky%20duck

I wish to use wacky duck in my story but I can't use it before I am sure that it means as I read in Urban Dictionary. I wish to know is this expression correct, does anyone use it? Some area or city? Maybe it is new expression that not many people know? I asked few people but nobody ever heard about this expression :(. I hope somebody will know the answer. Thank you in advance :o).

Comment: I've never heard it; I don't think you can rely on many readers being familiar with the expression. (Without context I would've guessed it was a term for a slightly crazy person.)

Comment: As almost everybody here knows, UD mostly has its nose in the gutter,  and the gutter differs from city to city.

Comment: If you Google it, "wacky duck" has been around for over 70 years, as a Marvel cartoon character.

Comment: I am not sure that Urban qualifies as a reputable source, so I am  VTCing for "lack of research".

Comment: Welcome! Interesting question. I have Never! heard the term but if it is very new I could certainly be behind the times. I would look for a different term to describe the same action.

Comment: A Google Books search for "wacky duck" turns up more than 50 readable matches for the term. Most refer to cartoon character ducks—and not one is remotely related to the slang sense that you cite from Urban Dictionary. I wouldn't trust any definition posted on Urban Dictionary unless I could find independent corroboration of its accuracy or unless the posted entry includes one or more citations of published examples of the claimed usage (which almost none of the entries at Urban Dictionary does).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on the premise that the UD definition is accurate. The best any answer can do will be "No, Urban Dictionary is wrong and it's probably just a troll who wrote the entry".

Comment: The gesture you name is a **goose.** Don't goose friends after leaving first grade.